# Looking for a better solution to create conditional columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following

```
df:

id,flag,amt 

10,1,100 
11,0,100
13,1,100
14,0,100
```

current code :

```
def func(row):
    if row['flag'] == 1:
        val = row['amt'] * 2
    else:
        val = row['amt']
    return val

    df['op'] = df.apply(func,axis=1)
```

output:

```
df:

    id,flag,amt,op 

    10,1,100,200
    11,0,100,100
    13,1,100,200
    14,0,100,100
```

Is there a better way to implement this? This solution is taking time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in bulk with:

```
df['op'] = (df['flag']+1) * df['amt']
```

This gives us:

```
>>> (df['flag']+1) * df['amt']
0    200
1    100
2    200
3    100
dtype: int64
```

In case `df['flag']` can have other values than `0` and `1`, we can use `np.where(..)`, like:

```
df['op'] = np.where(df['flag'] == 1, 2*df['amt'], df['amt'])
```

Comment: @piRSquared: well I honestly did not copy this. But like the Zen of Python says: there should be "*There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.*" :)

Comment: Oh!  Don't misunderstand me.  I never thought you did.  Just stating the coincidence.  Also, nice to see you on the [pandas] tag.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you very much. I didn't understand the 1st solution. But the 2nd one is simple and easy to implement. Doe the job. Thank You!

Comment: @HarikrishnanBalachandran: if `flags` is `0` and `1` then `df['flags']+1` has values `1` and `2`, so that can act as the multiplier here, since `1*` will just return `df['amt]`, and `2*` will double it.

Answer (score 3):

A bit longer version;

```
c=df.flag.astype(bool)
df['op']=np.where(c,df.amt.mul(2),df.amt)
```

---

```
   id  flag  amt   op
0  10     1  100  200
1  11     0  100  100
2  13     1  100  200
3  14     0  100  100
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Another option

This is no better than the other options but it might expand someone's understanding of things.

```
df.assign(op=df.amt + df.amt * df.flag)

   id  flag  amt   op
0  10     1  100  200
1  11     0  100  100
2  13     1  100  200
3  14     0  100  100
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do:

```
df['op']=df['amt']
df['op'].loc[df['flag'].eq(1)]=df['amt'].apply(lambda x:x*2)
```

or

```
df['op']=df['amt']
df['op']=df['op'].mask(df['flag'].eq(1)).fillna(df['amt ']*2)
```

Output:

```
    id  flag amt    op
0   10  1    100    200
1   11  0    100    100
2   13  1    100    200
3   14  0    100    100
```